# How to add subreport using ireports?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have added the subreport for the main report to print the values of invoice id,duedate and total by taking the details from invoice db table.
But I could not print the fields by using the parameters.
Please anyone can help me.I am new to jasper reports design.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Subscription_details" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="70" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" >
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridHeight" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridWidth" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.SnapToGrid" value="false"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.Grid" value="false"/>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="customerId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="totalWithTax" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="carriedBalance" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select i.amount as amount,i.due_date as duedate,i.id as invoiceId from invoice i where i.id=$P{invoiceId};]]>
</queryString>
<field name="description" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="price_per_item" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="quantity" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="amount" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>

<columnHeader>
    <band height="34">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="12" y="10" width="100" height="16" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Racun od]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="180" y="10" width="70" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Nacl Pl.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="374" y="10" width="70" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Iznos]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="12" y="33" width="543" height="1" />
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </line>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="263" y="12" width="100" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Broj Racuna]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="484" y="12" width="71" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Otvoreno]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="17">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="154" y="0" width="100" height="11" >

            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{duedate}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<summary>
    <band height="20">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="261" y="1" width="113" height="15" forecolor="#000000" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Ukupno CHF . . . .
       ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="344" y="0" width="100" height="13" >
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{amount}!==null)]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="12" y="1" width="543" height="1" />
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </line>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="254" y="17" width="301" height="1" />
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </line>
    </band>
 </summary>
 </jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps to adding a subreport to iReport. I will do my best to step by step explain

**STEPS:**

1) Make blank report with the values that will be used as parameters in your future subereport

2) *Drag the subreport element into the **Detail band ONLY***.

3) When the wizard pops up- use either an existing report or create a new one.

4) Use the design query to drop the fields you will need in the subreport

5) Make sure you use the same connection used to fill the master report

6) Now drop the fields and such on your subreport and design it. Any value that you make a parameter out of like "Part.num" then you must include it in your initial master report.

7) Head over to the master report and click the subreport box and scroll down on the properties tab. Where you see the field "Parameters". Double click to open and hit add. M***ake sure you name this parameter the exact same as the way you have it named in your subreport*** and then simply search for the field and hit okay.

8) Compile them both and continue to do the exact same steps for each parameter you either add or take away from the subreport/subreports.

I hope this helped and if you have any questions let me know.

**SOURCE:** http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/subreports-jaspersoft-studio